# iterate over multiple vectors in range based for loop

Tags: c++, c++17

I have two vectors of the same element type and want to iterate over a concatenated version without actually creating a concatenated vector.

Is there some thing like `zip` (but not in parallel)

```
std::vector<int> vec1{0,1,2};
std::vector<int> vec2{3,4,5};

for (const auto& e : fancy_util::zup(vec1, vec2)){
  std::cout << e << ", ";
}
```

should print `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,`

Is there something like the `fancy_util::zup`?

Comment: Sounds like you want [`views::concat`](https://wg21.link/p2542).

Comment: @cpplearner  yes! but I want it here, now and in C++17 ;-)

Comment: now&here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/284257/implementing-a-concat-range-view-using-c-stdranges